# How to distinguish between audio file and video file?

Tags: java, media, libvlc, vlcj

I am using Java to write a media application.

Given a file, how can I know is it a audio file or video file?

By the way, I use vlcj library.

Comment: On what platform?  For instance, if you're writing java for windows, the file extension is the indicator of the file type.  Beyond that, if the file is a media file that can support audio and/or video, then you have to look at the actual file format itself to know how to process it.

Comment: There's no guarantee that a file extension matches its contents. A quite easy way is to take few first bytes of the file as most multimedia formats put some kind of sign of file content that way. Bitmap starts with BM, AVI with DIFF, etc. You have to look for all formats you'd like to detect.

Comment: I am using windows. I agree leledumbo that file extension is not reliable. At lease 3gp format may be both sound or video.

Comment: And could you give me some keyword to search about the "first few byte" Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java 7 you will be able to use [`java.nio.file.probeContentType`](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29) to do this.

In the meantime, there are [a number of other options](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html) for doing this kind of thing.